# Clicking a toggle button on a web page

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA interface in Excel to a share trading website called SpectrumLive.

When clicking a toggle button from within VBA in Excel to buy or sell nothing happens.

The VBA I use is:

theDocument.getElementsByTagName(theTag).Click

The HTML is:

```
<div id="primary_tradetypeContainer" class="formrow">
<div id="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_primary_tradetype_error" class="error_field">
<span class="inline primary_order">
<label id="TradeType" class="Label" title="Sell/Buy:" for="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_primary_tradetype">Sell/Buy:</label>
<div id="MenuMgr_WM_view4_widgetbfcca409xc930x42d5x8d00x04a83ed68e5f_ordertab_primary_tradetype" class="toggleButtons sell">
<a id="sell" class="btn sell active" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0);">
***<a id="buy" class="btn buy" tabindex="0" href="javascript:void(0);">***
</div>
</span>
</div>
```

The particular fields have ID "buy" and sell above.

Thanks heaps for your help!

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery like :

```
$('#theTag').toggle();
```

Comment: I have an Excel sheet with VBA code, which interacts with the the browser. Can I use  JQuery from within VBA?